# 'Waiting' animation in command prompt (Python)

Tags: python, animation, command

I have a Python script which takes a long time to run. I'd quite like to have the command line output to have a little 'waiting' animation, much like the swirly circle we get in browsers for AJAX requests. Something like an output of a '\', then this is replaced by a '|', then '/', then '-', '|', etc, like the text is going round in circles. I am not sure how to replace the previous printed text in Python.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `\r` and print-without-newline (that is, suffix with a comma):

```
animation = "|/-\\"
idx = 0
while thing_not_complete():
    print(animation[idx % len(animation)], end="\r")
    idx += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

For Python 2, use this `print` syntax:

```
print animation[idx % len(animation)] + "\r",
```

Comment: Works great with me (when changing 'thing_not_complete()' to 'True'), excellent little animation!

Comment: [Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534142-spin-cursor/) is something pre baked.

Comment: What would change in Python 3 in the print line?

Comment: @ProgSnob Amended answer.

Comment: Is it possible to make the "\r" it work in the python IDLE. In the IDLE (3.7 on windows) all characters are just printed one after another...

Answer (score 12):

Just another pretty variant

```
import time

bar = [
    " [=     ]",
    " [ =    ]",
    " [  =   ]",
    " [   =  ]",
    " [    = ]",
    " [     =]",
    " [    = ]",
    " [   =  ]",
    " [  =   ]",
    " [ =    ]",
]
i = 0

while True:
    print(bar[i % len(bar)], end="\r")
    time.sleep(.2)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 6):

A loading bar useful for if you're installing something.

```
animation = [
"[        ]",
"[=       ]",
"[===     ]",
"[====    ]",
"[=====   ]",
"[======  ]",
"[======= ]",
"[========]",
"[ =======]",
"[  ======]",
"[   =====]",
"[    ====]",
"[     ===]",
"[      ==]",
"[       =]",
"[        ]",
"[        ]"
]

notcomplete = True

i = 0

while notcomplete:
    print(animation[i % len(animation)], end='\r')
    time.sleep(.1)
    i += 1
```

if you want to make it last a couple seconds do

```
if i == 17*10:
    break
```

after the

```
i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for best practices you can put a if condition at the end of the loop **to avoid overflow** with  'idx' variable in the case where the waiting funtion last longer than expexted:

```
import time

animation_sequence = "|/-\\"
idx = 0
while True:
    print(animation_sequence[idx % len(animation_sequence)], end="\r")
    idx += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)

    if idx == len(animation_sequence):
        idx = 0

    # Verify the change in idx variable
    print(f'   idx: {idx}', end='\r')
```

Comment: or simply instead of idx +=1 and the overflow test :

(idx = idx +1)%4

Answer (score 0):

I liked the aesthetic of @Warren and built upon it to allow a personalization.

```py
import time

# User Specification
bar = '========'
width = 8

bar_length = len( bar )
total_width = width + 2 * bar_length

t0 = time.time()
idx = 0

while time.time()-t0<30:
    string = f'{idx * " " + bar: <{total_width }}'
    substring = string[bar_length:bar_length+width]
    print(f'[{substring}]', end='\r')
    idx = (idx + 1) % total_width 
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

This approach saves the need to specify each 'frame' of the loading bar and allows you to replace `bar` with *anything* you want to see flying across the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Python's built-in [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) package contains utilities for controlling what is printed to a terminal screen.

Comment: curses has nothing to do with this post. he was just asking about a animation loop, ofc you can make in curses but that is not the answer for this post.